# Object initialization does not respect passed property value

Tags: c#

The code below was written for testing only, it mixes auto property setting with "palin old method" of property setting.

I noticed that that creating the instance p1 did not properly set the value for the Status property when the initialization was invoked (it shows as zero). However, as expected, setting the property outside the intialization statement works correctly.

My quesiton is why did the statement below failed to set the Status property?

```
Person p1 = new Person("71" ,"Sue", Person.ACTIVE_STATUS);
```

The complete code is:

```
public class Program {
 public static void Main()
 {
     Person p1 = new Person("71" ,"Sue", Person.ACTIVE_STATUS);
     Console.WriteLine("Id={0}, Name={1}, Status={2}",p1.Id,p1.Name,p1.Status);
     //from the above, here the status=0    -----(A)
     p1.Status=Person.ACTIVE_STATUS;
     //here status is = 1111                -----(B)
     Console.WriteLine(p1.Status); 
 }
public class Person {
 public const int ACTIVE_STATUS = 111;
 public const int INACTIVE_STATUS = -2;
 private string _id;
 private string _name;

 public Person(String Id, String Name, int Status) 
 {
  this._id = Id;
  this._name = Name;
 }
 public string Id        {get {return this._id;}} 
 public string Name      {get {return this._name;} set {_name=value;} }
 public int Status       {get; set;} //Auto property
}
}
```

Comment: also your code markup is very confusing... maybe read the msdn code guidelines because this is quite hard to read. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/. ill post some code with what i mean specifically if i have the time - gotta go now.

Comment: @sommmen, thank you. This was a very quick test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Person(String Id, String Name, int Status)
    {
        this._id = Id;
        this._name = Name;
        this.Status = Status;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes of course, but I am using auto properties. I expected that property will automatically be set without the need of a field.

Comment: Check MS documentation - you need that [Status = Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It is good. The confusion is that auto properties don't require an intermediate field, that was my impression.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you dont do anything with that argument specified in the constructor:

```
 public Person(String Id, String Name, int Status) 
 {
  this._id = Id;
  this._name = Name;
 }
```

Change that to:

```
 public Person(String Id, String Name, int status) 
 {
  this._id = Id;
  this._name = Name;
  Status = status;
 }
```

instead of passing a value to the constructor you can also direcrtly assign a property with a public setter e.g.:

```
Person p1 = new Person("71" ,"Sue", Person.ACTIVE_STATUS);
p1.Status = Person.ACTIVE_STATUS;
```

or you can use the object initializer:

```
Person p1 = new Person("71" ,"Sue", Person.ACTIVE_STATUS)
{
   Status = Person.ACTIVE_STATUS
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes of course, but I am using auto properties. I expected that property will automatically be set without the need of a field.

Comment: that is not what an auto property is at all. you can assign a public prop after construction which i think is what you mean

Comment: I updated the answer, is this what you mean? these are auto-properties btw: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties it's  just a property with a backing field but you don't explicitly create the backing field, thats done for you.

Comment: @NoChance, auto-*implemented* property simply means that compiler will automatically implement a full property for you (with private weirdly named back-field, which you promised to not need). It has nothing to do with constructor parameters.

Comment: @Sinatr, thanks for your comment. The confusing part is that the intermediate field is still required.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. In your last example,  If no intermediate field will be used, there is no value in including the status in the "new (....)" and no use for having "{...}". The signature of the constructor would need to change.

Comment: @NoChance the last sample is equal to the sample above it, it just assigns the property via the setter. what do you mean by intermediate value?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I fully understand that the last example is the same as the one before. What I wanted to say is that the constructor is using an intermediate variable namely "statatus" for an automatic property. Any way I get it now and I was confusing two different concepts. Thanks again.